# oracle plsql json query return array, loop this array

Tags: json, oracle

I have a table  with clob column and it contains json data,
I am trying to parse this, using JSON_query, one of the attribute in json data is array,

```
select  JSON_query(v.json_sub_pojo,'$.systemAcronyms')
        , v.* 
from notf.ver v
```

returns

```
["ONE","TWO"]
```

I need help in loop the values of array.

Comment: see json_table - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/function-JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-37CBD672-5B0A-4FAB-A3AF-144E76686BD5

Comment: How do you expect the result set to look?

Comment: {"subscription":"my@mail.aws","systemAcronyms":["ONE","TWO"],"carrierId":null,"subscriptionType":"EMAIL"}

select t.* from
 notf.ver v,
json_table(v.json_sub_pojo,'$.systemAcronyms[*]'
columns(sa varchar2(100) path '$')
) as t
where v.verification_id=..


this worked